# How Many Acute Angles

Tags: geometry

[image]

Knowing that the big angle is 90, how many acute angles we have in this shape?

I know acute angle is less than 90, so we have 4 acute angles between the inner lines. Also we have 3 more acute angles combining the above angles. So the total will be 7 acute angles.

But the answer says its 9 acute angles, what am I missing?

Comment: You forgot the two cases , where three angles are combined.

Comment: I'd hardly call this a geometry problem any more than I'd call the beetles in four corners crawling toward each other a biology problem.  This is a basic combinatorics problem that uses a picture of angles as it's subject.  Anyway, you have 4 "distinct" acute angles.  Combine two and you have 3 more.  Combine three and you have 2 more.  (Combine all four and you get a right angle). It's a basic question about the way to combine objects where only adjacent objects can be combined.  The answer is to add 1 + 2 +3 +4 (but one if them is a right angle and doesn't count.)

Comment: In your case, we have 3 lines and the answer is 9 angles(see below). More interesting "How many acute angles we get if we would have used $n$ lines?", the answer is $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}-1$.

Comment: As always, I believe in expressing things simply when they are simple. I hope that unlike some other answers, mine makes the matter as simple as it really is.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Your answer *was* very simple.  But I think all the others were too.  It's only the comments that were complicated.

Comment: "Also we have 3 more acute angles combining the above angles. ...
 what am I missing?"  THe only thing you are missing is how many ways there are to combing the above angles. You got that you can combine two adjacent to get 3 more. But you missed that you can also combine three adjacent to get 2 more after than. How to count *all* combinations can be confusing to keep track and how to do so systematically is what combinatorics is all about. In this case the trick is to count the single  angles ( there are 4) and the double adjacent ( 3) and so on. Patterns and "tricks" become apparent.

Comment: Select two lines of the five: 5C2 = 10, leave out the right angle and you get 9.

Answer (score 6):

You have 9 different angles in that figure:
[image]

Comment: @MichaelHardy, Anything else?!

Answer (score 2):

Call the five rays $A,B,C,D,E$, going clockwise, so that $A$ is horizontal and $E$ is vertical. Then acute angles correspond to
$$
AB,\quad AC,\quad AD, \quad BC,\quad BD,\quad BE,\quad CD, \quad CE, \quad DE
$$
That's nine acute angles.

Answer (score 1):

Let $O$ be the common vertex, and $A,B,C,D,E$  be the other 5 vertices in clockwise order. Observe that, we have the following 9 acute angles -
$\angle AOB$, $\angle AOC$, $\angle AOD$, $\angle BOC$, $\angle BOD$, $\angle BOE$, $\angle COD$, $\angle COE$, $\angle DOE$.

Answer (score 1):

There are ${5 \choose 2} - 1 = 9 $ acute angles because you can select any two of the rays except the outermost pair, which are at right angles.